# Empty rows are not dropped in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv file

Link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9e9c0c38776ee527e179c36dd28873f520231102165242/7d1470

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\AllStock.csv')
df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
df.dropna(axis=0, how ="all", inplace = True)
df
```

I tried to run the above code to delete empty row, but the result is the same as original. Empty rows are not deleted. Please help

Please let us know for any wrong coding with explanation

Comment: Are you sure you have rows that have only NA values? What do you get from `df.isna().all(axis=1).sum()`

Comment: it display 0, but may I ask why? It shows NaN when i read it in python

Comment: How should i delete the row like that? thank you very much

Comment: Code should work OK. `how='all'` means **all** the row must be NaN to be removed. Your test giving 0 says you have no such rows.  You need to decide which columns have NaN and so indicate the row is to be removed.

Comment: i am quite confused as when i read the data in excel, it is empty cell, how come when it read in pandas it is not empty?

Comment: This df has 2256 columns - it would be easy to miss a row with only one non-NaN value if you are just looking in excel or the abbreviated output of the python shell.

Comment: An approach you could use it to decide on a column which should **always** have a value (eg a column named `fullcol`) then delete all rows with NaN in the that specific column by using: `df = df[df[fullcol].notna()]`

Comment: Please test for actual presence of fully empty rows. You may use this: `df[~df.isnull().all(axis=1)]` which will restrict the view to fully empty rows. What does it yield for you? It looks like it is going to be empty (Rather reply inside the body of the question rather than in a further comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to delete blank rows in a column, I use subset.

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Date'])
```

I hope it helps you